# Comparar valores de varios arrays contidos num array em PHP

Tags: php, array, arraylist

```
<?php
    $productos = array(
      'producto1' => array(
           'preco'=> 25,
           'quantidade' => 5
       ),
      'producto2' => array(
           'preco'=> 20,
           'quantidade' => 50
       ),
      'producto3' => array(
           'preco'=> 10,
           'quantidade' => 100
       ),
    );
?>
```

Gostaria nesse caso comparar os produtos e retornar o produto com menor preço e maior quantidade. Nesse caso seria o produto 3.

**EDIT**

Se um produto tiver o menor preço mas quantidade não for a maior, o preço deve ser a prioridade.

Comment: Mas e se um produto tiver o menor preço mas quantidade não for a maior? Ou vice-versa? Como se deve processar. Por exemplo: `'producto4' => array(
               'preco'=> 1,
               'quantidade' => 50
           ),`
Se este produto estivesse também no teu exemplo

Comment: @Miguel realmente, nesse caso o preço passa a ser a prioridade. Editei a questao ! Valeu

Comment: Acho que pode ser duplicada, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ordenar+array+php

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, no final o preço deve ser sempre a prioridade. De qualquer forma, você pode usar `array_multisort()` para ordenar o seu array e depois retornar o conteúdo do primeiro índice.

```
<?php
    $productos = {...};

    foreach ($productos as $key => $row) {
       $preco[$key]  = $row['preco'];
       $quantidade[$key] = $row['quantidade'];
    }

    array_multisort($preco, SORT_ASC, $quantidade, SORT_DESC, $productos);

    $menor = $productos[0];
?>
```

O `var_dump()` do array irá mostrar:

```
array(3) {
    ["producto3"]=> array(2) {
         ["preco"]=> int(10)
         ["quantidade"]=> int(100)
    }
    ["producto2"]=> array(2) {
         ["preco"]=> int(20)
         ["quantidade"]=> int(50)
    }
    ["producto1"]=> array(2) {
         ["preco"]=> int(25)
         ["quantidade"]=> int(5)
    }
}
```